# Why is category HOME required?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have these categories defined in my application manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If I remove the line -

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>`

It does not affect any part of the application functionality and I can see my application in the home screen launcher list of my android device.

However, If I remove the last line -

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

I see the change that my application gets disappeared from home screen launcher list of my android device.

So my question is what's the purpose of this category HOME and what's its common use.

If the only purpose of this category is to launch the home screen as mentioned in the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME), then this I can do by the following also:

```
Intent homeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Comment: you know that we can make own launchers ? check: `ANDROIDSDKPATH\samples\android-17\Home`

Comment: where is the link to check?

Comment: On your hdd ... if you download a sdk samples

Comment: That's fine. We can make launcher by putting that `category.LAUNCHER` inside the particular activity to launch. How about `category.HOME` ?

Comment: AFAIK, LAUNCHER makes activity visible in launcher and HOME makes activity a launcher(aka Home Screen)

Comment: So if I remove the `category.HOME` from activity, then that activity should not become a launcher ?

Comment: it will be a launcher but not work as home screen replacement app..

Comment: "home screen replacement app" meaning customized home screen displays like themes using our application ?

Comment: that is right @VedPrakash

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

indicates that when you press home button, your app will be listed as an option to launch the launcher home or your home activity (along with all the applications which have this category in their manifest for an activity). To be more simple, whenever you press the home button, all the applications  installed in your phone which have CATEGORY.HOME category and Action_Main  in intent-filter in their AndroidManifest.xml will be listed (unless you have chosen some application as default) in a chooser for the user to select which HOME they want to launch.

Comment: Not working on AndroidTV