# restart my app activity on home button pressed

Tags: android

I want to disable all 3 button back button task and home button **only for 1 activity** , i found a way for back and task button its working.

But I am facing problem for home button disable .. if disabling is little complicated , just restart my app activity when user pressed home button , will also worked for me !

Any suggestion or help how can i do it ?

following is my code

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        {

            return false;
        }
        else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {

        }
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB)
        {

        }

        else {
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
        return  false;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The home button and recents button are supposed to take you home and show the recents picker. Why would you interfere with what is an expected behaviour by all users?

Comment: i am trying to make screen lock which open as mobile completes root and user have to enter password .. no other option to close that activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the new version of Android prevent us to override the Home button... sorry for that!

However, you can do something when the button is pressed. You need to override onPause()

**EDIT:** I tried this, and it worked (even though it's really ugly...):

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "Pause");
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: its not working :( 

protected void onPause() {


  super.onPause();



  startActivity(new Intent(this,FirstActivity.class));
 
}

Answer (score 1):

if someone looking for answer following might help,
Just add this one line in manifest activity tag

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

i.e.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this line at the activity in the manifest.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

Using this, when user press the home button the system will ask you if you want to open for one time or always, select always and when user press home button will open the activity with the categoty home declared

[Why is category HOME required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590204/why-is-category-home-required)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to be overriding onKeyDown

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        //stuff here!                 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```